# Error code: Unhandled Exception (Identation error)

Tags: python-3.x, django, indentation, pythonanywhere, unhandled-exception

Claro, a tradução para o inglês seria:

"I can't make sense of this set of errors. It's not making any sense in my head."

[Image of the error message provided by the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwE91.png)

[Image of the error in the log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcmnU.png)

wsgi code

```
# +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
# To use your own Django app use code like this:
import os
import sys
# assuming your Django settings file is at '/home/horaciobarret1/project/project/settings.py'
path = '/home/horaciobarret1/project/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
```

I would like my link to work normally on the server

Comment: The Python interpreter is saying that there is an indentation error at line 7

Comment: yes, i know. But i don't know what is the error. And I used four spaces, not tab